# Persistent connection with queries from server to client

Tags: c#, .net

I have a company network under my control and a couple of closed customer networks. I want to communicate from a web application in my network to a database inside a customer network. My first idea was:

- Web application stores query in a database in the company network and waits for answer.
- Windows service inside client network polls our database a couple of times every second through a (WCF) web service also in our company network.
- If a query is available the Windows service executes it in it's local database and stores the answer in the company database.

I've been thinking about removing the polling idea and instead using persistent connection between a client in the customer network and a server in our company network. The client initiates the connection and then waits for queries from the server. What would be better or worse compared to polling through a web service? Would WCF be the right thing to use here?

Comment: I think a persistent connection (always on) is not the best use for WCF.  WCF is more along the lines of "open, use, close".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have few approaches:

- WCF Duplex, Once the web application stores a query in database, you initiate a call to the client (in this case the Windows Service) instead of making the windows service polls every few seconds. net.tcp will be good choice but still you can use http.
- Long polling, Instead of letting your Windows Service client sends a request every few seconds, let it send the request, the channel is open, set the timeout in both client and WCF service for longer time, let the server method loops and checks the database for new notifications. Once new notifications found, the method returns with them. At Client side, once you get a return send another request to the server and then process the data. If timeOut error occure, send another request. Just Google Long polling you will find a lot.
  Regarding querying the database every few seconds, the better approach would be making a table for notifications, So instead of querying a large table with a complex sql string every few seconds you can let the client add the notifications in a separate table (after they are done adding them the main table), so your query will be much simpler and takes less resources. you can add direct pointers (Like Ids) in the notifications table to save time. Later clean up the notifications table..

Comment: The client can't receive any connections.

I like the long polling idea. My first polling idea is already in use. It will not require much to use long polling instead. Thanks!

Comment: it will require minor changes, put the db qury in a loop, use Thread.Sleep(int ms) within the loop so you dont overload the db. make the timeout longer. make the client request back the method once it returns.. and you are good to go :)